# Jinja nested template not found

Tags: python-3.x, flask, jinja2

I've got the following structure in my flask project:

```
app
   -app
     -static
     -templates
       -layouts
         footer.html
         header.html
         main.html
       search.html
     __init__.py
     app.py
     MANIFEST.in
     setup.py
```

In app.py:

```
@app.route('/search')
def show_search_form():
    return render_template('search.html')
```

search.html:

```
{% extends "layouts/main.html" %}

{% block body %}

Test

{% endblock %}
```

main.html

```
{% include 'header.html' %}

{% block content %}

{% endblock %}

{% include 'footer.html' %}
```

header.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>App</title>
</head>
<body>
```

footer.html

```
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, I'm extending main.html into search.html and using (in this case) 'Test' as content to be injected in the body block. But it doesn't work, I'm getting the following error:

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: header.html
```

What's wrong with the code?

Comment: Where do those files sit in your directory structure?

Comment: @MattHealy sorry, just added the files to the structure

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your footer.html and header.html files are under the layout directory, you need to reference them as such in the main templates:

**main.html**

```
{% include 'layouts/header.html' %}

{% block content %}

{% endblock %}

{% include 'layouts/footer.html' %}
```

Comment: Yeah, I had tried out that already but didn't work either:
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: layout/header.html

Comment: Shouldn't that be "layouts" instead of "layout"?

Comment: Yes sir. You're right. After fixing the spelling I'm not getting an error but a blank page instead of the text 'Test'

Comment: Never mind. The only reason why I was getting now an empty page was because I was referencing 'body' block (which doesn't exist) instead of 'content' block